# PHP GD imagescale quality

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I have a script scaling down high resolution photos. I use GD with the imagescale function with IMG_BICUBIC_LINEAR algorithm. After downscaling, I sharpen the images with a convolution matrix.

But I am not happy with the quality. Images look worse than resized with other tools. Is it impossible to get good quality with GD functions or do I do something wrong. Should I just use imagick?

Comment: My experience: Imagick is faster, easier and has much more options.

Comment: I converted my code to use imagick and the image quality looks much better even with the default settings. The code became simpler too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to start using Imagick. PHP GD functions cannot be customized enough to produce better quality.